# Swapping individual lines of two dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays

so I have a question in school I've been trying to solve for a while now, but I just can't figure it out how do do it right.
So the task at hand hand is to swap the array lines with the smallest and biggest integer in python, but I just can't figure it out. I know how to find the biggest and smallest integers in the arrays, but have no clue how to swap them.
So if I have for example:

```
array1 = 
[[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

how do i make it:

```
array1 =
[[97, 98, 99, 100]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Any input or idea how to solve it on my own is very much appreciated!

Comment: arrays do not look like that. I would expect something like `array1=[ [line1], [line2], ..., [linen] ]`

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, apply `min` and `max` to find smallest and largest number, then specify their locations with `argmin`, `argmax`. Finally swap the rows.

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [97, 98, 99, 100]])

# find the row indices of min and max
imin = np.argmin(np.min(array1,axis=1)) 
imax = np.argmax(np.max(array1,axis=1)) 

# swap the rows
array1[[imin,imax]] = array1[[imax,imin]]
```

Output:

```
[[ 97  98  99 100]
 [  5   6   7   8]
 [  9  10  11  12]
 [  1   2   3   4]]
```